# Determining the range of $f(x) = \sqrt{\frac1{x-3}+2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a quick question about determining the range of a square root/reciprocal function:

$$f(x) = {\sqrt {\frac1{x-3} + 2}}$$

I have attached the Geogebra graph of this function, and with this, we can determine the range to be

$$y \in \mathbb{R} : 0 \le y \lt \sqrt 2 \text{ or } y \gt \sqrt 2$$

Would there be a way to determine the range of this function without the use of graphing technology?

Thank you.

Edit: I suppose I am also asking how one would find the horizontal asymptote in this example, or is this only possible by graphing?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the square root function always produces either a zero or positive value. Here $\frac{1}{x-3}+2$ is continuous everywhere expect at $x=3$. So your function inside the square root can take any value except $3$.So the range should include all positive values , including $0$ except $\sqrt{2}$. Clearly $\sqrt{2}$ can not be in the range as that would imply $\frac{1}{x-3}=0$ which is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can first determine the range of expression inside the square root, $\frac{1}{x - 3} + 2$, which should be in $(-\infty, 2)\cup(2, \infty)$.  *(note that: $\frac{1}{x - 3} + 2$ is just what we get when move $\frac{1}{x}$ 3 unit right and 2 unit up)*

Then just find the range of $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ in the domain of $(-\infty, 2)\cup(2, \infty)$, which is just $(-\infty, \sqrt{2})\cup(\sqrt{2}, \infty)$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, looking at the function, we can see that taking the square root of a negative argument over real numbers is not permitted, so we get the lower bound that $f(x)\geq 0$

We cannot divide by $0$, so we automatically consider when $x<3$ and $x>3$ separately

The easier of the two is when $x>3$. The fraction is positive, even when $x$ is barely bigger than $3$. If this is the case, then we're dividing by a decimal between $0$ and $1$. If we call this small decimal $\delta$, then

$$\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\frac{1}{\delta}\to\infty$$

And

$$\sqrt{\infty}=\infty$$

Likewise, the bigger $x$ gets, the smaller the fraction becomes, then we're adding $2$ and then taking the square root. In particular, the argument is always positive, so $f(x)$ is definitely defined on $(3,\infty)$

This implies its range is $(\sqrt{2},\infty)$ because

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x-3}\sim\frac{1}{\infty}=0$$

Then $$\sqrt{0+2}=\sqrt{2}$$

How about when $x<3$? How about when $x$ is right under $3$, like $2.999$? In this case, we're taking $\frac{1}{2.999-3}=\frac{1}{-0.001}=-1000$. Then $-1000+2=-998$.

We can't take the square root of negative numbers over the reals, so we need to find the threshold value of $x$ when $\frac{1}{x-3}+2=0$

Multiply both sides by $x-3$ to get

$$\left(\frac{1}{x-3}+2\right)(x-3)=0(x-3)\implies1+2x-6=0\implies2x=5\implies x=\frac{5}{2}$$

This means $f(x)$ takes on no values between $2.5$ and $3$

How about $x<2.5$? We get kind of the same situation we had with $x>3$, but now the fraction is negative, which seems problematic, but its getting ever smaller as $x$ decreases.

$$\lim_{x\to{-\infty}}\frac{1}{x-3}\sim-\frac{1}{\infty}=0$$

So again we get

$$\sqrt{0+2}=\sqrt{2}$$

In summary

Domain: $(-\infty,2.5]\space\longrightarrow\space$ Range: $[0,\sqrt{2})$

Domain: $(2.5,3)\space\longrightarrow\space$ Range: None

Domain:$(3,\infty)\space\longrightarrow\space Range:(\sqrt{2},\infty)$